# Open Source Politics: How is it produced? Decisions, power and gender

Tags: linux

I hope this is the right forum to ask that question!

I think that computer skills and programming knowledge will be THE decisive factor for the generations to come. I think each and every child everywhere in the world should learn how to code and master a computer.

As I am very interested in the political implications of that, I am looking for articles, scientific publications and blog entries on the politics of the open source community (especially concerning Linux and programming languages, but open to Wikipedia and other common effort projects).

My questions are:
- How many people are really involved and how are actions and decisions distributed (my guess: 1% do 95% of the work)?
- How are the productive networks distributed locally? How much is decided and programmed in the US and Europe, how much elsewhere?
- How are women involved? Do they contribute differently and what initiatives are working for getting more women into computing?

Cheers!

Comment: No, this isn't the right forum. This site is for [**users** of unix-like systems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq), not about politics or sociology.

Comment: Ok, do you have any recommondations for where I could ask that question?

Comment: There's a [proposed site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) about [politics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25906/politics), but your questions are a bit specialized for that, and anyway the site isn't going to go live for at least a few months. I don't see a sociology proposal. The Stack Exchange site [ubuntu.se] fields the occasional non-technical question, so you could try asking this question specifically about the Ubuntu project; if your question isn't welcome there at least people would know where to redirect you.

Comment: For questions about open source development projects, I wonder if you could ask on [programmers.se]. I've never been been clear as to whether sociology questions are ok there.

Comment: I disagree with your basic premise @mmb and the creator of SE has a nice writeup about it here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/05/please-dont-learn-to-code.html

Comment: in addition to what @gilles has said, this site is *not* about *open source* it is about as he says *unix* and *unix like* systems. There is, in fact, open source software that does not run on unix.

Comment: I see! I think there is a need for discussing these topics, but maybe not on any of the stackexchange sites.

Comment: @mmb: If you combine the "impact" curiosity in your question with sound technical skills, interest and activity, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it and you should not be discouraged just because this isn't the right place to discuss it. If you're just in it for the blaha blaha, I'd say it is a bit pathetic, like for example physically extremely passive people being extreme fans of boxing and ice hockey (just an example). But like I said, if you are in "both worlds", go for it.

Comment: A [programmers.se] moderator says no to this question: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5461649#5461649